# Is it possible to use a string as variable keys for a multdimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$test = ['hi'=>['ho'=>1] ];
$str = 'hi[ho]';
var_dump ( isset($test[$str] ) );
```

In this example the variable test has a key of 'hi' and the key 'hi' is a multidimensional array with another key of 'ho'.

I am looking for a way to access the ['hi']['ho'] via a string. Something akin to $test[$str] .
This is a simplified example and the real code will have multidimensional arrays with up to 10 deep, but the concept will still be the sam.e

Comment: How tied are you to the "hi[ho]" format? Would "hi.ho" notation work for you instead?

Comment: I'm not 100% married to it, but it is being parsed via GET parameters. So that may effect those.

Comment: Take a look at the [CakePHP Hash utility class](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/hash.html#Cake\Utility\Hash::extract), specifically the `extract` function.